# In Access, how can I compare a truncated division with the real division on linked table in SQL server

Tags: ms-access, vba

My Access 2010 database has a linked table (on a SQL Server 2012 backend), containing fields ID, Qty, PackSize.  My query is meant to select records where Qty is not a multiple of the packsize. Normally I achieve this with a where clause like so: "Where Qty/Packsize <> Fix(Qty/Packsize), but although this works on local tables or linked tables that live in other Access databases, on linked tables which live in SQL server, it returns no results.

If I split up the query into two parts, one with no where clause, creating a new table with ColA: Qty/Packsize, ColB: Fix(Qty/PackSize), and then select where ColA <> ColB, it works fine.

Since I don't really care what the values are, just to know whether they're different, I also tried Int() instead of Fix.

Even weirder, "Where Cdbl(Qty/Packsize) = int(Qty/Packsize)" returns all the records, despite showing me that Cdbl(Qty/Packsize) is for example 425.5 and int(Qty/Packsize) is 425.

Any idea what's going on or how I can achieve this another way? It needs to be in a single step though, as it's really the basis for a record selection in VBA. Why would it not work over a SQL linked table? I've tried in separate databases as well and using a different SQL table, in case it was merely a glitch.

Many thanks in advance.

(Also the title of this question is awful. Edits gratefully received.)

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior. Please try to provide an [mcve]. For me, it tends to just work. You can try making it a pass-through query, that has the added advantage of usually being faster. To remove decimals in SQL server, you can use casting functions: `CAST(Qty/Packsize AS INT)`, and you can cast back to a float when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a floating point issue, so try with integers only:

```
Where Qty <> Fix(Qty/Packsize) * Packsize
```

By the way, Fix and Int behave the same for positive values.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Have a nice weekend!